# Getting TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send an array of object from my node.js to react.js but i'm getting an error `TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function` maybe because i'm trying to do following

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 res.writeHead(200);
 res.end(JSON.stringify(data,null,3));
```

inside a nested database query, from my point of view i do not know why i can't send a response `res` on my vscode it says `res is declared but its value is never read` here's a sample code

```
app.get("/gettemperature", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.query.email;

    //step1 get device ip from database using
    let stmt = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?`;
    let todo = [email];
    console.log("email: "+email);
    
    db.query(stmt, todo, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        let userid = results[0].id;
        console.log(userid);
        let getID = `SELECT * FROM controlModules WHERE deviceowner=?`;
        let getidData = [userid];

        db.query(getID, getidData, (err, results, fields) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
          }

          if (results.length > 0) {
            const lanip = results[0].ipaddress;
            console.log(lanip);
            //step2 get temp where device ip
            //for local connection
            let url = "http://"+lanip+"/data";
            http.get(url,(res) => {
              let body = "";
      
              res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                  body += chunk;
              });
      
              res.on("end", () => {
                  try{
                      let json = JSON.parse(body);
                      const temperature = json.temperature.value;
                      const humidity = json.humidity.value;
                      const waterlevel = "";
                      const nutrient = "";

                      console.log(temperature);

                      let date_ob = new Date();
                      let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
                      let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                      let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
                      let hours = date_ob.getHours();
                      let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
                      let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();
                      const dateStamp = month+"/"+date+"/"+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes

                      if(lanip != ""){
                        //getting parentid
                            console.log(userid);
                            let inserreport = `INSERT INTO report(date,farm,temperature,humidty,waterlevel,nutrientsolutionlevel) VALUES ()`;
                            let inserreportval = [dateStamp,userid,temperature,humidity,waterlevel,nutrient];
                            
                            //inserting to childtable
                            db.query(inserreport, inserreportval, (err, data, fields) => {
                              if (err) {
                                // res.send(err);
                              }

                              //success inserting to table then get inserted data
                                console.log(userid);
                                let getreport = `SELECT * FROM report WHERE farm=?`;
                                let getreportval = [userid];
                                console.log("getreportval "+getreportval);

                                //getting report list
                                db.query(getreport, getreportval, (err, results, fields) => {
                                  if (err) {
                                    // res.send(err);
                                  }
                                  let data = [];
                                  for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                                    data.push({
                                      date: results[i].date,
                                      temperature: results[i].temperature,
                                    });
                                  }

      //===========>node.js server crashes here
                                  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                  res.writeHead(200);
                                  res.end(JSON.stringify(data,null,3));
                                });
                              
                            });
                      }
                  }catch(error) {
                      console.error(error.message);
                  };
              });
      
          }).on("error", (error) => {
              console.error(error.message);
          });
            //end of step2
          }
        });

        
      }

    });
    
  });
```

Comment: you use parameter name "res" twice. just rename one of the parameters to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: wait which part and how?

Comment: ok so i tried only using ```res.send(JSON.stringify(data,null,3));``` and removed the ```res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                  res.writeHead(200);``` but i did get an error ```TypeError: res.send is not a function```

Comment: There is no `setHeaders` function in express

Comment: `res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: tried ```res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");``` but got an error ```TypeError: res.set is not a function```